# hard disk locked and no password to unlock it, how and what do I do about it

Tags: laptop, disk-utility

Hard disk in the laptop it came with when I switch on the system it shows me a space for password and I don't have any idea of what the password could be and when I put it (hard disk) in an external hard disk pack and try running it in another system it doesn't come up at all, I have also tried running the hard disk in another system it still request a password.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Do you mean to forget to login the power-on password?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't come up at all" ' no entry at all or just the name with no access...

Comment: @solar mike what I mean is in external hard disk pack when I plug it in my system or any system normally it was supposed to load by it self or at least checking my PC I will see it there, but none of them happens.

Comment: @daidai I will post the screenshot as soon as i can.

Comment: @daidai am not allowed to post pics said I need at least ten reputations to post pics